# UI freezes on creating objects in bulk, even using a task

Tags: wpf, user-interface, asynchronous, async-await, freeze

I have a method `OnLoadShapeFilePolygonsCommand()` which reads the polygon (geometry) details from a file and creates some objects. These are then loaded in an observable collection which is bound to a datagrid.

While all these processing, I am showing a progress bar. Just added a progress bar with the `IsIndeterminate` property set to `true` and when all data is loaded I set the progress bar's visibility to `false`.

My problem is, while polygon objects are created, the UI gets frozen (the progress bar hangs).

Am I doing something wrong here? Please help.

```
private async void OnLoadShapeFilePolygonsCommand()
{
    // ...
    // some code

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        List<Ploygon> collection = new List<Ploygon>();
        foreach (Graphic g in graphics)
        {
            collection.Add(new Ploygon(g,.. .. ..);
        }
        return collection;
    },CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
    .ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, ThreadStart)delegate ()
        {
            // MapPolygons is observable collection binded to datagrid.
            MapPolygons.AddRange(antecedent.Result);
            //...
        });
        },scheduler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `await` with `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `ContinueWith`?

Try this instead:

```
var collection = await Task.Run(
    () => graphics.Select(g => new Ploygon(g,.. .. ..)).ToList());

// MapPolygons is observable collection binded to datagrid.
MapPolygons.AddRange(collection);
...
```

Comment: When creating more than 350 objects, progress bar got frozen for sometime, it was not refreshing. but there was improvement.

Comment: When did it froze?

Answer (score -2):

You are using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781658(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method, providing a `TaskScheduler` as an argument.

You obtain a `TaskScheduler` using the static method [`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx). As you can read in the docs, this method returns a `TaskScheduler` associated with the current `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext`.

Since you call the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method (and so the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` method too) on the UI thread, you're actually using the UI thread's `TaskScheduler` to enqueue your work. This is the explanation for your freezing UI.

One side-note: `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` is useless here, because you specify this option for the parent task. Why are using this option at all?

Instead of using the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method, use the shortcut method `Task.Run` (of course, if you target .NET 4.5 or later).

Alternatively, use the `TaskScheduler.Default` instead of `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.

Comment: To people blindly downvoting an answer: please try my solution and see that it's correct and works. Is the explanation not good enough?